# Example from Mathematica documentation (ExtremeValueDistribution) seems to be evaluating "forever"

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, evaluation, distributions, documentation

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

I am referring to this example at the reference page for the extreme value distribution: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ExtremeValueDistribution.html#6764486

The first three commands seem to be running ok, but the last line of code just will not stop evaluating on my machine (MathematicaMark9 result > 1.5) - somthing seems to be very wrong:

```
Show[DiscretePlot[Mean[max\[ScriptCapitalD]], {n, 2, 100}, PlotStyle -> Orange], 
 Plot[approxMean, {n, 2, 100}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thick, Dashed]]]
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is that a mistake in the documentation or an error in Mathematica 9.0.1?

*Edit: I added the* `bugs` *tag because it seems clear by now that this is really a bug in Version 9.0.1, see answer and comments below.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem appears to stem from evaluating `Mean[max\[ScriptCapitalD]]` for values of `n` greater than 5. For `n` between 2 and 5, the evaluation takes place in more-or-less constant time. For `n = 6`, the timing jumps to over 247 seconds (on my system).

```
NestList[
  {#[[1]] + 1, First @ AbsoluteTiming[Mean[max\[ScriptCapitalD]] /. n -> #[[1]] + 1]} &, 
  {1, 0},
  5]
```

> ```
> {{1, 0}, {2, 1.217399}, {3, 1.220662}, {4, 1.221624}, {5, 1.220797}, {6, 247.914156}}
> ```

I smell a bug in `OrderDistribution`.

#### Update

I reported this problem to WRI tech support. I have received the following reply:

> Thanks for reporting the issue. I've sent your message to the corresponding development team and I will keep you posted if I hear any news from them. Thanks again for bringing the problem to our attention!

This may be regarded as official WRI confirmation that the behavior by vonid is a bug.

#### Update 2

In V10 the bug hasn't been fixed, but the documentation has been revised to use a work-around. In the definition of `max\[ScriptCapitalD]` in the referenced example, `NormalDistribution` is passed machine precision reals as the values for its mean and standard deviation arguments. In the V9 documentation, `NormalDistribution` was called without arguments and used the default exact values 0 and 1.

```
max\[ScriptCapitalD] = OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[0., 1.], n}, n];
Table[val = {i, First@AbsoluteTiming[Mean[max\[ScriptCapitalD]] /. n -> i]}, {i, 6}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1.006853}, {2, 1.010143}, {3, 1.010674}, {4, 1.013509}, {5, 1.013680}, {6, 1.027929}}
> ```

The evaluation of `Mean[max\[ScriptCapitalD]]` is now done in what is essentially constant time.

Comment: I get {{1, 0}, {2, 0.797534}, {3, 0.789527}, {4, 0.793531}, {5, 
  0.799535}, {6, 160.987567}} on my machine which confirms the effect.